# C++ parse datetime string with "last"-day notation

Tags: c++, datetime, parsing, c++20, c++-chrono

[`std::chrono::year_month_day_last`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day_last) provides a very convenient way to express last days of year/month pairs.

Is there a possibility using [`std::chrono::parse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/parse), [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, C++11, header-only datetime library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) or [boost](https://www.boost.org/) to parse a date-string where the "last" part is modeled as the value zero or the absence of a value, f.e. parse "2023-01-00" or "2023-01" as `year_month_day_last{2023y / January / last}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the `last` part being modeled with the string `"last"`?

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

date::year_month_day
my_parse(std::istream& is)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    year_month_day result{};
    year_month ym;
    is >> parse(" %Y-%m-", ym);
    if (!is.fail())
    {
        if (isdigit(is.peek()))
        {
            day d;
            is >> parse("%d", d);
            if (!is.fail())
                result = ym/d;
        }
        else
        {
            string word;
            is >> word;
            if (word != "last")
                is.setstate(ios::failbit);
            else
                result = ym/last;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

For C++20, drop `#include "date/date.h"` and `using namespace date;`.

Just read in a year, month and the trailing `-`, and then test to see if you have a number or not following.  If number it is a day number, else it better be the string "last".

[The beginning space in the format string matches zero or more white space characters.](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.parse#15.sentence-8)

This could be exercised with:

```
int
main()
{
    using namespace std;

    istringstream in{"2023-01-30 2023-01-last"};
    in.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    auto date1 = my_parse(in);
    cout << date1 << '\n';
    auto date2 = my_parse(in);
    cout << date2 << '\n';
}
```

which outputs:

```
2023-01-30
2023-01-31
```

Comment: I like the "last" model but short term i'm looking for a drop in replacement :) Here's the [slightly modified version](https://godbolt.org/z/Gen7hdrv8).